# これの名前なんて言うんですか?

Tags: unity3d

unityでオブジェクトなどを操作するこれの名前ってなんて言うんでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 6):

「ギズモ」です

UnityのWebページに詳しく書いてあるのでざっと眺めると入りやすいかと思います
http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html